# How to get file signature, files type (*.exe, *.js, *.msi, *.ocx, *.sys, *.vbs)?

Tags: file, signature

I am developing tool to make signature test be easy, already i succeeded to pull out signature from dll files using .net C# reflection.
i want to know if the reflection in C# will help me to get signature from the below list,  files type :(*.exe, *.js, *.msi, *.ocx, *.sys, *.vbs).

if not, then how can i get the signature (from list above)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below :

```
string copyright = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path).LegalCopyright;
```

will get the copyright from all the wanted files.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection can only be used to reflect over .NET assemblies (dll and exe that *are* .NET assemblies).

You cannot reflect over other types.

What do you mean by getting the `signature` from a file?

Comment: File signature found : win 7 :  
r.click on file -> properties -> digital signature -> will view the signature   of the file.  

I need to go over 4000 files automatically and pull out the signature from each   file and save it as text then to test it by comparing it with the wanted   signature, to be sure that all the files pass the signature!

Comment: @Kimo - sorry, I don't know much about extracting digital signatures from files.